# how to know if the map contains that object based on the object properties

Tags: java

I am using a map and want to use a value object as a map key..and a list as value. The value object has 2 properties first name, second name..i want to return map.containsKey() as true if both properties matched by some key in the same map..

I tried to use comparator as below

```
public class comaparatorEx  implements Comparator<Test>{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Map m= new HashMap<Test,List<String>>();
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setFirstname("vamsi");
        t.setSecondname("priya");

        List descriptionList=new ArrayList();
        descriptionList.add("description1");
        m.put(t, descriptionList);
        Test t2 = new Test();
        t2.setFirstname("vamsi");
        t2.setSecondname("priya");

        if(m.containsKey(t2)){
            System.out.println("user found");
        }           
    }

    public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
    if((o1.firstname.equals(o2.firstname) )&& o1.secondname.equals(o2.secondname))
        return 0;
    else return 1;
    }
}
```

this is the value object i am using

```
public class  Test  {

String firstname;
String secondname;

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getSecondname() {
    return secondname;
}
public void setSecondname(String secondname) {
    this.secondname = secondname;
}

}
```

But it returns false for me..please help me ..thanks in advance

Comment: t is a different object. You can't find it using the object of t2 as you are doing here - m.containsKey(t2). If t and t2 were integers then it would have worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `HashMap`, you need to overwrite `equals` and `hashCode` in your class.

Possible implementation:

```
class Test
{
  ...
  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
     return 31*firstname.hashCode() + secondname.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
     // basic type validation
     if (!(obj instanceof Test))
        return false;

     Test t = (Test)obj;
     return firstname.equals(t.firstname) && secondname.equals(t.secondname);
  }
}
```

`Comparator` is for comparison-based collections such as `TreeMap`. To use this, supply an instance of this class in the constructor:

```
Map m = new TreeMap<Test,List<String>>(new comaparatorEx());
```

But there is a problem with your `compare` function - there needs to be logical ordering between the elements (there isn't as you never return `-1`). `String` has a `compareTo`, which you can just use:

```
public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
  int result = o1.firstname.compareTo(o2.firstname);
  if (result == 0)
    return o1.secondname.compareTo(o2.secondname));
  else
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In `if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Test))` the first comparison is not needed.  `obj instanceof Test` will be false if `obj` is null.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to override the default equals method in your test class.

you can write something like this.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(null != o && o instanceof test && o.attr1.equals(this.attr1)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

containskey In map looks at the equals method. More info in [the java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)

The implementation of equals i have given is just an example. For a proper implementation you should [read this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17)

Comment: Testing for `null != 0` is absolutely pointless as it is always true.

Comment: @ViktorSeifert That was meant to be o. have edited the answer.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Your implementation of `equals` is good.  You can omit `null != o` since `o instanceof test` is false if o is null.  But you also must override `hashCode` if you overrride `equals`, otherwise you break the contract of `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap uses the hashCode() and equals() methods, internally, to determine e.g. what buckets to look in, and whether the objects in that bucket are the same.  You will need to implement both for your Test class, otherwise it will effectively default to reference equality (i.e. are they the exact same object)

Answer (score 0):

You need override the `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods to give meaningful equality between the `Test` object.
`HashMap` insertions is bassed on the `hashcode`.
When we pass an both key and value to `put()` method to store on `HashMap` , it uses key object `hashcode()` method to calculate `hashcode` and they by applying hashing on that `hashcode` it identifies bucket location for storing value object and keys equals () method will be used to identify correct key value pair in HashMap .

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html#ixzz2fDozSqmi